# An object inside its own class

Tags: java, object

So let's say:

```
public class Sample {  //main() class
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      A a = new A();
    }
}

public class A {
  A aa = new A();
}
```

1. So...when I run it ...it gives :  java.lang.StackOverflowError.
   So, my explanation is that object `a` generation at line 1, furthers creates object `aa` generation at line 2...and then it enters a recursion .... which keeps creating object after object, until the heap memory is full.
2. If the objects are created on Heap...then why does it say StackOverflowError ??

Comment: If you set your stack sufficiently large and your heap sufficiently small then it _will_ generate an error when you run out of heap space.

Comment: A constructor is a method. Each constructor invocation takes space on the stack.

Comment: The objects are created on the heap, but the references to those objects are created on the stack. More objects = more references = stack overflow

Answer (score 4):

Well, it's using both heap *and* stack. The stack space is because you're in the constructor for `A`, recursively. It would be simpler to see this if you put the initialization in the body of the constructor:

```
public class A {
  A aa;

  public A() {
     aa = new A();
  }
}
```

So the `A` constructor calls itself, then calls itself, etc. There's generally rather more heap space available than stack space, hence why you're running out of stack space first. If your class had a lot of fields, you would conceivably run out of heap space first - although usually the heap is pretty huge in modern machines.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for a stack overflow is simply that the stack runs out of space before the (small) As can fill up the heap.

You have correctly recognized the recursion. So!